# Cheap keyboard with programmable keys and backlit keys

Tags: keyboards, windows, led

I'm looking for a keyboard under $100USD for gaming, programming, and video editing. For these, programmable keys are needed.

**Requirements:**

- Extra programmable keys
- Backlit keys with adjustable brightness(and able to easily turn lights off)
- Media control buttons (Play/pause/stop/skip)
- Full sized keyboard (With numpad)
- Works with Windows 10

**Would like, but not required:**

- I've seen some keyboards with plugs for headphones/USB; having these would be good
- Having multiple light colors to choose from (If not changeable, a green color would match my PC)
- Volume switches for PC
- I don't like really small keyboards, so if its bulky, I consider that a plus.

Comment: I would recommend the Corsair K70, but it's out of your price range.

Comment: If you cannot find a keyboard that has programmable keys, there is always the third party application [Auto Hot Key](http://ahkscript.org/) to help fill in the gap.

Comment: The only problem may be with changeable colors. G710+ mentioned in my answer seems to be fine for you ;). http://www.amazon.com/dp/B009C98NPY

Comment: There was a question a while back about keyboards in which I recommended a CODE keyboard. Can't remember any of the specs offhand, but I know mine has a numpad and backlit keys, and definitely works with Win X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about [Logitech G105](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBUCCKO). Price: $39.99 .

According to your spec:

- **6 programmable G-keys**: Configure up to 18 unique functions per game, including single key presses, complex macros or intricate Lua scripts* (*Requires software installation)
- Long-life blue LED backlighting (**Two different brightness levels plus Off**)
- **Quick-access media controls:** volume, mute, start, stop, pause, forward and back functions.
- It works with Windows 8 and you don't have to care about W10 compatibility. It's more about marketing rather than specific adjustment.
- Game/desktop switch: Disables the Windows/Context Menu keys to prevent accidental game interruptions
- It's a full-size keyboard and seems to be solid

[image]

**If you want to have an extra USB think about [Logitech G710+](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009C98NPY)**

The nice thing about G710+ is cable routing underneath the keyboard:
[image]

Check also:

[Logitech G710+ Mechanical Gaming Keyboard Unboxing & First Look Linus Tech Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUI-htHPUpM)

[image]

Comment: One note about the G105: The media keys are not dedicated keys. They are on the F keys and require you to press the `Fn` key to utilize. Other than that, this is a good keyboard.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Luckily, Logitech G710+ is cheaper than $100 and has these buttons placed separately (volume control, mute and media playback).

Comment: The G105 also isn't mechanical, while the G710+ is.