# Programmable non-mechanical keyboard?

Tags: keyboards, programmable

I'm looking for a non-mechanical programmable keyboard.

**Requirements**

- *Not* mechanical i.e. I want a membrane or rubber dome keyboard.
- Fully programmable. I really like how the Pok3r lets you program layers separately and it's easy to switch between layers. I'm looking for something similar.

**Nice to have**

- Tenkeyless or 60% layout.
- Backlit, preferably white but RGB is OK if the color can be adjusted.

So... any suggestions?

**Edit**: I did take a look at [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/416/cheap-keyboard-with-programmable-keys-and-backlit-keys), but I'm looking for a fully-programmable board, that is, (nearly) every key should be programmable, not just a few.